# How to Correctly Install Tensorflow on Windows x64-bit Python 3.6.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

When I first used `$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow`, I was unable to install it. After looking around on multiple sites, I realized that it was because I had installed the x32-bit version of Python, not the x64-bit. After uninstalling the old Python and installing the new one, I was able to install tensorflow. This was the output:

```
C:\Users\Seth>pip install --upgrade tensorflow --user
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/2a/c3fe6035f0a8726e5b210680af3ccaf826f4a64ce7306e57017aba749447/tensorflow-1.10.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting absl-py>=0.1.6 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/86/67f55488ec68982270142c340cd23cd2408835dc4b24bd1d1f1e114f24c3/absl-py-0.4.1.tar.gz
Collecting gast>=0.2.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/78/ff794fcae2ce8aa6323e789d1f8b3b7765f601e7702726f430e814822b96/gast-0.2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools<=39.1.0 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (39.0.1)
Collecting wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/30/e935244ca6165187ae8be876b6316ae201b71485538ffac1d718843025a9/wheel-0.31.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.6.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/df/d606d07cff0fc8d22abcc54006c0247002d11a7f2d218eb008d48e76851d/protobuf-3.6.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting astor>=0.6.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/6b/11530768cac581a12952a2aad00e1526b89d242d0b9f59534ef6e6a1752f/astor-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tensorboard<1.11.0,>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c6/17/ecd918a004f297955c30b4fffbea100b1606c225dbf0443264012773c3ff/tensorboard-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/da/03e722b7981ab3222f292f735a3c157b1d1bca120c479d7e273273828170/grpcio-1.14.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/48/a76be51647d0eb9f10e2a4511bf3ffb8cc1e6b14e9e4fab46173aa79f981/termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.13.3 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/b7/0c804e0bcba6505f8392d042d5e333a5e06f308e019517111fbc7767a0bc/numpy-1.14.5-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8 (from tensorboard<1.11.0,>=1.10.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/7d/488b90f470b96531a3f5788cf12a93332f543dbab13c423a5e7ce96a0493/Markdown-2.6.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.10 (from tensorboard<1.11.0,>=1.10.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/c4/12e3e56473e52375aa29c4764e70d1b8f3efa6682bef8d0aae04fe335243/Werkzeug-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, absl-py, gast, wheel, protobuf, astor, numpy, markdown, werkzeug, tensorboard, grpcio, termcolor, tensorflow
  Running setup.py install for absl-py ... done
  Running setup.py install for gast ... done
  The script wheel.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script markdown_py.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script tensorboard.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Running setup.py install for termcolor ... done
  The scripts freeze_graph.exe, saved_model_cli.exe, tensorboard.exe, tflite_convert.exe, toco.exe and toco_from_protos.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed absl-py-0.4.1 astor-0.7.1 gast-0.2.0 grpcio-1.14.2 markdown-2.6.11 numpy-1.14.5 protobuf-3.6.1 six-1.11.0 tensorboard-1.10.0 tensorflow-1.10.0 termcolor-1.1.0 werkzeug-0.14.1 wheel-0.31.1
```

I thought it had worked until I imported it in a program. This was the result of that:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION

Thank you P-Gn for marking this as a duplicate. I would not have found the answer otherwise. Tensorflow works in version 1.5 for me, but I will probably have to find a way to get 1.10 working.

Answer (score 0):

Download Anaconda. It comes with installed tensorflow and other libraries. Check out this [website](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows)

Comment: Similar error occurred when I tried with Anaconda.

Comment: what did that error say?

Comment: Here is the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/HR2x1i35